# Why aren't the changes I'm making (using pickle module) saved?

Tags: python

I have just started to learn about pickle module and trying to write a code for an exercise (program that should save dictionary to a file and retrieve it each time is starts again).

The program I wrote is working OK, the thing is whenever I open it again the changes I'm doing are not saved to the file (I think). When I try to debug only the first data I entered remains.

Can you point out my problem?

Here's some of my code

```
import pickle
    def main():
        ofile=open('pickledveg.dat','ab')
        ifile=open('pickledveg.dat','rb')
        try:
            vegdct=pickle.load(ifile)
            print (vegdct)#check
        except EOFError:
            vegdct={}
#changes im(well the user) making here work ok(can see by printing vegdct after each change)
        ifile.close()
        pickle.dump(vegdct,ofile)
        ofile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do the same work in a simpler and more readable way. Basically, you can read a file this way:

```
pickle.load(open('myfile', 'rb'))
```

and overwrite this way:

```
pickle.dump(vegdct, open('myfile', 'wb'))
```

What's more, if you do:

```
pickle.dump(vegdct, open('myfile', 'ab'))
```

(what you're currently doing), you will just append your changes to the end of your file. So, I think you're just appending some changes that you don't see. I hope this helps.

Comment: choice=0
    while choice!=QUIT:
        choice=get_menu_choice()
        if choice==Look_up:
            look_up(vegdct)
        if choice==Add:
            add(vegdct)
        if choice==Change:
            change(vegdct)
        if choice==Delete:
            delete(vegdct)
this is the missing part of my main function. maybe im not clear enough... first im adding a pair, (by saying change i mean changing the value of a key in the dictionary).after, i use the function lookup so i can see that the change is saved. but if i close and then open again the pair i enter first is saved

Comment: and any change that im doing from now on is not saved for further use.